# Retrasmit sse using jax-rs jetty

Tags: jetty, jax-rs, osgi, server-sent-events

I try to re - transmit sse from an osgi plugin . I have this code and at the moment i can only read the sse from event source and print it out in the console correctly. The sse write part is not working properly and buffering instead. Is there any way to fix it and read and write from the same function?
Thanks in advance!

```
@ApplicationPath("MySensor")
public class MySensor extends ResourceConfig {
    private static String sensorA = "smotion";
    // private static String sensorB = "sdist";
    // private static String sensorC = "slight";
    private int id = 0;
    private String idn = "";

public MySensor() {
    super(MySensor.class, SseFeature.class);
}

// creates new broadcaster
private static SseBroadcaster BROADCASTER = new SseBroadcaster();

@MethodDescription(value = "sse")
@GET
@Consumes(SseFeature.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
@Produces(SseFeature.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
public EventOutput getServerSentEvents() {
    id = id + 1;
    idn = sensorA + " " + id;
    BROADCASTER.broadcast(new OutboundEvent.Builder().data(String.class, idn).build());

    // System.out.println(BROADCASTER.);

    String LocalNetworkIP = "192.168.1.134";

    EventOutput eventOutput = new EventOutput();
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().register(SseFeature.class).build();
    WebTarget target = client.target("http://" + LocalNetworkIP + "/" + sensorA);
    EventInput eventInput = target.request().get(EventInput.class);

    while (!eventInput.isClosed()) {

        InboundEvent inboundEvent = eventInput.read();

        if (inboundEvent == null) {
            break; // connection has been closed
        }
        try {
            // handleevent
            // inboundEvent.readData(String.class);
            System.out.println(inboundEvent.readData(String.class));
            OutboundEvent.Builder eventBuilder = new OutboundEvent.Builder();
            eventBuilder.name(inboundEvent.getName());
            eventBuilder.data(inboundEvent.readData(String.class));
            OutboundEvent event = eventBuilder.build();
            eventOutput.write(event);
            BROADCASTER.add(eventOutput);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error when writing the event.", e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

        }
    }

    try {
        eventOutput.close();
    } catch (IOException ioClose) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error when closing the event output.", ioClose);
    }

    return eventOutput;
}
```

Comment: Must i use Pull model or Push model?

Comment: I partially fix it without the event broadcaster, but i get only 6 retransmission's from jetty

Comment: P.S. The 6 re transmissions is a browser limitation for SSE!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Finally find it out!

```
@MethodDescription(value = "Return the Server Sent Event")
@GET
@Consumes(SseFeature.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
@Produces(SseFeature.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
public EventOutput getServerSentEvents() {
    id = id + 1;
    idn = sensorA + " " + id;

    final EventOutput eventOutput = new EventOutput();
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().register(SseFeature.class).build();
    WebTarget target = client.target("http://" + LocalNetworkIP + "/" + sensorA);
    final EventInput eventInput = target.request().get(EventInput.class);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public synchronized void run() {
            try {
                while (!eventInput.isClosed()) {
                    // Thread.sleep(500);
                    InboundEvent inboundEvent = eventInput.read();

                    if (inboundEvent == null) {
                        break; // connection has been closed
                    }
                    try {
                        // handleevent
                        // inboundEvent.readData(String.class);
                        System.out.println(inboundEvent.readData(String.class));
                        OutboundEvent.Builder eventBuilder = new OutboundEvent.Builder();
                        eventBuilder.name(inboundEvent.getName());
                        eventBuilder.data(inboundEvent.readData(String.class));
                        OutboundEvent event = eventBuilder.build();
                        eventOutput.write(event);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        try { //extra
                            eventOutput.close(); //extra
                            eventInput.close(); //extra
                        } catch (IOException ioClose) { //extra
                            throw new RuntimeException("Error when closing the event output internal.", ioClose); //extra
                        }    //extra  
                        throw new RuntimeException("Error when writing or reading the event.", e);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (!eventOutput.isClosed()) { //extra
                        eventOutput.close();       //extra
                    }                              //extra
                    if (!eventInput.isClosed()) {  //extra
                        eventInput.close();
                    }                              //extra
                } catch (IOException ioClose) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Error when closing the event output.", ioClose);
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
    return eventOutput;
}

}
```

Comment: I anyone have any solution using broadcaster , fell free to post it